# Why can't I see the countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I tried to make a countdown timer using `setInterval()`. I used code made by other people to learn how, but it failed. After searching to find the issue, I was not able to find it.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Count</title>

    <script="text/javascript">
      var Stime = 10;   //Set time(minute)
      var Ssecond = Stime * 60;
      var countdownID=0;

      function inidown(){
        countdownID = setInterval("Count()",1000);
      }

      function Count(){
        if(Ssecond>0){
          var rM=Ssecond/60;
          var rS=Ssecond%60;
          document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=rM+":"+rS;
          Ssecond--;
        }
        else{
          clearInterval(countdownID);
          document.getElementById("out").innerHTML="time out";
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body onload="inidown()">
    <div id="count"></div>
    <div id="out"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I saw that code on http://blog.niklasottosson.com/?p=665

```
var Stime = 10; //?? ??(?)
var Ssecond = Stime * 60;
var countdownID = 0;

function inidown() {
  countdownID = setInterval("Count()", 1000);
}

function Count() {
  if (Ssecond > 0) {
    var rM = Ssecond / 60;
    var rS = Ssecond % 60;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = rM + ":" + rS;
    Ssecond--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(countdownID);
    DivCount.innerHTML = "Time Out";
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "time out";
  }
}
```

*No error occurs in that code.*

Comment: Please share what part is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There was a problem with your script tag.
2. Use Math.floor for your minutes.
3. Pad the seconds for single digits.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Count</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Stime = 10; //Set time(minute)
    var Ssecond = Stime * 60;
    var countdownID = 0;

    function inidown() {
      countdownID = setInterval("Count()", 1000);
    }

    function Count() {
      if (Ssecond > 0) {
        var rM = Math.floor(Ssecond / 60);
        var rS = ("0" + (Ssecond % 60)).slice(-2);
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = rM + ":" + rS;
        Ssecond--;
      } else {
        clearInterval(countdownID);
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "Time Out";
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body onload="inidown()">
  <div id="count"></div>
  <div id="out"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO. Please mark a response as the answer if you found the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`<script="text/javascript">` should have a `type` attribute `<script type="text/javascript">`

`setInterval("Count()",1000);` works, but can also be rewritten as `setInterval(Count,1000);`

With these changes it is working.

Comment: Note that `type` attribute is optional for HTML5 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Comment: Indeed, but since the original code includes `="text/javascript"` without a type there is an error. It could optionally be left out entirely.

Comment: It is also preferred to use `setInterval(Count, 1000);` instead of `setInterval("Count()", 1000);` because if the parameter is a string, it is the equivalent of using `eval`, to evaluate the string into a function. And using `eval` is bad practice.